# Haskell - Checking if a list contains an element atleast N times

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I am writing a function that checks if a list containts an element at least N times

```
atLeastNtimes :: Eq a => Int -> a -> [a] -> Bool
atLeastNtimes n a l = n <= (sum [1 | x <- l, (x == a)])
```

It is working fine with finite list, but I am struggling to make this work for infinite lists, for example:

```
atLeastNtimes 100 'a' (repeat 'a')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few possible alternative approaches:

- Define your function recursively, without ever trying to inspect the full list but only the needed prefix.
- Start by `filter`ing the list so to keep only the elements you want to count. Then, use `drop (n-1) xs` to drop `n-1` elements (if any), and check if the resulting list is not empty (use `null`). Note that `drop`ping more elements than those in the list is not an error, and it will result in an empty list.

Comment: Thank You @chi! 
atLeastNtimes n a l = not $ null $ drop (n-1) (filter (==a) l) works perfectly fine

Comment: Or `atLeastNtimes n a = not . null . drop (n - 1) . filter (== a)`.

Answer (score 2):

We can separate the problem into two parts. The first just checks whether a list is long enough.

```
-- | Check whether the length of a list
-- is at least a certain value.
lengthAtLeast :: Int -> [a] -> Bool
lengthAtLeast n0 xs0 = foldr go stop xs0 n0
  where
    stop n = n <= 0

    go _ _ n | n <= 0 = True
    go _ r n = r (n - 1)
```

The second is filtering, which `filter` does for you. So

```
atLeastNtimes :: Eq a => Int -> a -> [a] -> Bool
atLeastNtimes n a = lengthAtLeast n . filter (a ==)
```